# D8 Widget Column is missing on manage field page

Tags: 8, entities

I haven't worked with Drupal for a long time and particularly I never worked with D8. Looks like the manage fields screen doesn't have widget column. Specifically I would like to use https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form widget for entity reference field, but I couldn't figure out where do I go to change widget type for the reference field.

See screenshot:
https://screencast.com/t/eZvspoNHTDQv

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry for a stupid question. I figured it out. It was under "Manage form display" screen. What got me confused was while googling for answer, I stumbled upon a few screenshots from an early D8 build which still had Widget Type column on Manage Fields screen and it lead me into thinking that something was wrong with my installation.